# Can´t erase data from flash memory (STM32)

Tags: stm32, flash-memories, hal-library, stm32f4-discovery

I´m trying to save some data to flash memory on my **STM32F407** board. Before I can save them, I need to erase a memory sector. I chose 16 Kbytes **Sector1** starting with address 0x08004000 and chose **Voltage range 2.1-2.7 V**. I'm using HAL library.

Program stops responding after **FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_STRT;** line inside HAL_FLASHEx_Erase() -> FLASH_Erase_Sector() function.

I'm pretty sure it's my fault but I can't find out what is wrong.

```
HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
__HAL_FLASH_CLEAR_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_EOP | FLASH_FLAG_OPERR | FLASH_FLAG_WRPERR |
                           FLASH_FLAG_PGAERR | FLASH_FLAG_PGPERR | FLASH_FLAG_PGSERR);
FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef EraseInitStruct;
EraseInitStruct.Sector = FLASH_SECTOR_1;
EraseInitStruct.TypeErase = TYPEERASE_SECTORS;
EraseInitStruct.VoltageRange = FLASH_VOLTAGE_RANGE_2;
EraseInitStruct.NbSectors = 1;
uint32_t SectorError = 0;
if (HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&EraseInitStruct, &SectorError) != HAL_OK) {     
    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
    return;
}

uint16_t data = 300;
//----------------------------write data
if (HAL_FLASH_Program(TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, start_address, data) != HAL_OK) {
    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
    return;
}
HAL_FLASH_Lock();
```

Did I choose wrong voltage range or number of sectors?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Define "stops responding".  Are you trying to debug through this?  Don't expect that to work, as flash programming has tight hardware requirements.

Comment: I placed my breakpoint on line with HAL_FLASH_Program() function but my program has never reached it. After erasing memory it stops responding and I can wait how long I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. I used HAL_FLASH_Lock() function instead of HAL_FLASHEx_Erase() function and it works fine. I also changed SECTOR because I was accidently erasing my program.

```
unit32_t address = 0x0800C000;
HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
__HAL_FLASH_CLEAR_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_EOP | FLASH_FLAG_OPERR | FLASH_FLAG_WRPERR | FLASH_FLAG_PGAERR | FLASH_FLAG_PGPERR | FLASH_FLAG_PGSERR);

FLASH_Erase_Sector(FLASH_SECTOR_3, VOLTAGE_RANGE_3);

//----------------------------write data  
uint8_t data = 'A';
if (HAL_FLASH_Program(TYPEPROGRAM_BYTE, start_address, data) != HAL_OK) {
    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
    return;
}
HAL_FLASH_Lock();
```

Thanks for your help.